# How to override BlackBerry10 function?

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am making an application that is using tab bar with the "More" button. I would like to Override the swipe function and instead of OnClick on the "More" button, the help panel to pop up on swipe (from left to right).

[image]

The picture is showing the tabs and the fourth tab button is the "More" button.

Here is my main.qml file.

```
TabbedPane {
    showTabsOnActionBar: false
    Tab {
        title: "Home"
        Page {
            id: page1
            actions: [
                ActionItem {
                    id: new
                    title: "New"
                },
                ActionItem {
                    id: delete
                    title: "Delete"
                },
            ]

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: As @level32 said, you can check the state of the overflow menu. But you can't override it.

Answer (score 0):

Those are Actions, not Tabs. The "More" button is the Action Overflow Menu. You can listen for the state of this menu. [onActionMenuVisualStateChanged](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__page.html#function-actionmenuvisualstatechanged-newactionmenuvisualstate)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the TabbedPane (where you saw those graphics) you can "hange the appearance of the sidebar by setting the property sidebarState." So it would be possible using a GestureHandler to detect the swipe and set the sidebarState to VisibleFull.